# Выбор 1го элемента из списка веб-элементов Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте, 
работаю в Selenium (Java).

Пытаюсь получить список элементов, и выбрать только первый элемент. 
Список определяется, выдается количество в 15 элементов. Но у меня не получается кликнуть на первый элемент. Пример кода:

```
List<WebElement> list1 =  (List<WebElement>) d.findElements(By.tagName("ul")); 
list1.get(1).click();
```

Помогите советом. Спасибо.

[Ссылка для примера](https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=selenium%20webdriver)

Comment: Видимо вы кликаете на элемент, который еще не успел от рисоваться. Лучше всего это делать, через `JavascriptExecutor`.

Comment: get(1) разве не второй элемент?

Comment: что именно не получается? ошибка, не тот элемент кликается...?

Comment: Всем сасибо, все получилось сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте прописать следующим образом:

```
List<WebElement> list1 =  (List<WebElement>) d.findElements(By.tagName("ul")); 
WebElement e = list1.get(1);
e.click();
```

Но если Вы под словом "первый" имели ввиду его привычное понимание, а не программное, то:

```
WebElement e = list1.get(0);
```